# Null save into Shapefile using GeoTools

Tags: shapefile, convert, csv, geotools, null

When I convert CSV to Shapefile in GeoTools, I have an error NULL store for first attribute in my shapefile. e.g. -

Want result:

```
POINT(3625.55 3659.25), 2.4, 3.9
```

Error result:

```
Null, 2.4, 3.9
```

This is my program:

```
public class Csv2ShapeNew {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = getCSVFile(args);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        List<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<SimpleFeature>();

        SimpleFeatureCollection collection = null ;//= new ListFeatureCollection(TYPE, features);
        SimpleFeatureType TYPE = null;
        try {
            String line = reader.readLine();

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append("location:Point,");

            String[] headers = line.split("\\,");

            for (String header : headers) {
                stringBuilder.append(header).append(":String,");
            }
            //stringBuilder.append("location:Point,");

            TYPE = DataUtilities.createType("Location", stringBuilder.substring(0,stringBuilder.toString().length() - 1));
            //System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
            //System.out.println(TYPE);
            GeometryFactory factory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(GeoTools.getDefaultHints());

            for (line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
                String split[] = line.split("\\,");

                //String name = split[0];
                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(split[1]);

                Object[] o = new Object[split.length+1];
                //o[0]="";
                o[0] = (factory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude)));
                    for (int i = 1; i < o.length; i++) {
                        o[i] = split[i-1];
                    }

               /* for (int i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(o[i]);// = split[i-2];
                }*/


                    //o[1] = name;

                System.out.println(o[0]);
                SimpleFeature feature = SimpleFeatureBuilder.build(TYPE, o, "");
                features.add(feature);
                collection = new ListFeatureCollection(TYPE, features);
                System.out.println(features.get(0));
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        File newFile = getNewShapeFile( file );

        DataStoreFactorySpi factory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();

        Map<String, Serializable> create = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
        create.put("url", newFile.toURI().toURL());
        create.put("create spatial index", Boolean.TRUE);

        ShapefileDataStore newDataStore = (ShapefileDataStore) factory.createNewDataStore(create);
        newDataStore.createSchema(TYPE);
        System.out.println(TYPE);
        newDataStore.forceSchemaCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
        System.out.println(newDataStore.getSchema());
        //Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");

        String typeName = newDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];

        FeatureStore<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> featureStore;
        featureStore = (FeatureStore<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature>) newDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);
        //SimpleFeatureCollection collection = new ListFeatureCollection(TYPE, features);
         System.out.println(collection.getSchema());
        //featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
        try {
            featureStore.addFeatures(collection);
            //transaction.commit();
            System.out.println(featureStore.getDataStore());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            //transaction.rollback();
        } finally {
            //transaction.close();
        }
    }

    private static File getCSVFile(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file;
    if (args.length == 0){
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Open CSV file");
        chooser.setFileFilter( new FileFilter(){
            public boolean accept( File f ) {
                return f.isDirectory() || f.getPath().endsWith("csv") || f.getPath().endsWith("CSV");
            }
            public String getDescription() {
                return "Comma Seperated Value";
            }
        });
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog( null );

        if(returnVal != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        file = chooser.getSelectedFile();

        System.out.println("Opening CVS file: " + file.getName());
    }
    else {
        file = new File( args[0] );
    }
    if (!file.exists()){
        throw new FileNotFoundException( file.getAbsolutePath() );
    }
    return file;
    }
    private static File getNewShapeFile(File file) {
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    String newPath = path.substring(0,path.length()-4)+".shp";

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Save shapefile");
    chooser.setSelectedFile( new File( newPath ));      
    chooser.setFileFilter( new FileFilter(){
        public boolean accept( File f ) {
            return f.isDirectory() || f.getPath().endsWith("shp") || f.getPath().endsWith("SHP");
        }
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Shapefiles";
        }
    });
    int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

    if(returnVal != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    File newFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println(newFile);
    if( newFile.equals( file )){
        System.out.println("Cannot replace "+file);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return newFile;
}
}
```

Comment: did you call your geometry the_geom as the standard requires?

Comment: The problem is likely in your code, but since you haven't shown a minimal, compilable, complete example, its fairly hard to guess.

Comment: Thanks BradHards, attach my program please check and suggest me as soon as possible..

Answer (score 1):

shapefile expects geometry column name only "the_geom". Replace line:

```
stringBuilder.append("location:Point,");
```

with:

```
stringBuilder.append("the_geom:Point,");
```